# How to initialize a byte array in Clojure

Tags: clojure, arrays

What's the syntax for creating a byte array in Clojure initialized to a specified collection of values?

Something like this, but that works...

(byte-array [0 1 2 3])

Comment: your sample **does** work in later versions of clojure (tested in 1.8).  Not sure when it changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(byte-array (map byte [0 1 2 3]))

afaik Clojure has no byte literals.

Comment: Correct; as of Clojure 1.5, it does not have a byte literal: http://clojure.org/reader

Answer (score 4):

Other posters have given good answers that work well.

This is just in case you are doing this a lot and want a macro to make your syntax a bit tidier:

```
(defmacro make-byte-array [bytes] 
  `(byte-array [~@(map (fn[v] (list `byte v)) bytes)]))  

(aget (make-byte-array [1 2 3]) 2)
=> 3
```

Comment: A function would work just as well, right? This answer breaks the [first rule of Macro Club](https://clojurefun.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/when-do-you-need-macros-in-clojure/): Don't Write Macros!

Answer (score 1):

```
(byte-array [(byte 0x00) (byte 0x01) (byte 0x02) (byte 0x03)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(byte-array [(byte 0) (byte 1) (byte 2)])
```

Explanation:

`byte` creates a `byte`

`byte-array` creates a `byte[]`

<strike>`bytes` converts it to `byte[]`</strike>

Comment: byte-array creates byte[], so the call to bytes is not needed.

Comment: You are right. Repl automatically boxing primitives got me confused. Corrected

Comment: In fact, `byte` coerces to `byte`, although in 1.2 all arguments to functions are autoboxed, so `byte-array` still receives `Byte`-s and needs to unbox them. Try `(loop [i (byte 0)] (recur (Byte. 0)))` at a 1.2 REPL to verify this.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm testing the type with `(class (byte 1))` it will yield `java.lang.Byte` because it was boxed when passed to `class` function, although `(byte 1)` was a primitive `byte`.

Comment: Is the following garbage?  (class (byte-array [(byte 0) (byte 1) (byte 2)]))  which gives strange [B in the repl output.